# binutils - kernel - "_binary" meaning?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, kernel, binutils

I am reading xv6 lectures.
I have a file named initcode.S that is to be linked in the kernel.

Now two symbols are created that way :

```
    extern char _binary_initcode_start[], _binary_initcode_size[];
```

inside a function.

The lecture says :

> as part of the kernel build process, the linker embeds that binary that defines two special symbols, _binary_initcode_starcode_size, indicating the location and size of the binary.

I understand that binutils is getting the address and the size of this assembled code.

I wonder about the notation : is it default ? my searches didn't prove that clearly.

- `_binary` -> it is originally an assembly code
- `_initcode` -> the name of my file
- `_start` -> the parameter i am interested in.

It would imply that any assembly code compiled would have those variables too.

I have no proof of that, though.

---

**The question is** :

is `_binary_myAsmFileHere_myParameterhere` the default variable structure binutils give to the assembly file to export their address, size and so on ?

Could someone tell me if my assumption is right and if it is better than that : **the rule**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely enough, it doesn't seem to be documented in the `ld` manual. However, [man objcopy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) does say this:

> You can access this binary data inside a program by referencing the
>   special symbols that are created by the conversion process. These
>   symbols are called _binary_objfile_start, _binary_objfile_end and
>   _binary_objfile_size. e.g. you can transform a picture file into an object file and then access it in your code using these symbols.

Apparently the same logic is used by `ld` when embedding binary files.
Notice that the [Makefile](https://github.com/guilleiguaran/xv6/blob/master/Makefile#L113) for xv6 contains this line for linking the kernel:

```
$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -T kernel.ld -o kernel entry.o $(OBJS) -b binary initcode entryother
```

As you can see, it uses `-b binary` to embed the files `initcode` and `entryother`, so the above symbols will be defined during this process.

Comment: Waw.. Thanks again Jester. You are *very* knowledgeable! amazing :)

Comment: Note: It will be failed to define these symbols if the `objfile` preffix with directory part.

Answer (score 1):

when a .global variable is defined in an assembly file, for a C file to be able to reference that variable, the C file has to prepend a '_' to the variable name.  This is so the linker can 'link' the name in the C file with the name in the assembly file.